# Zend Framework, htaccess cannot read the new controller

Tags: zend-framework

my problem is.

my application has an image folder , and croping technique in zend framework so when the croped image requested and it found previously , the htaccess will cope the image  by calling crop model

```
the file requested   is : http://localhost/cmstest/public/contents/userdata/images/100X100/163.png
```

but the server  cannot read the right controller

htacces code here

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)  ../../index/index/app/storage/image/$2/crop/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

the error shown is

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (contents)
Stack trace:

#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cmstest/public/index.php(36): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'contents',
  'action' => 'userdata',
  'images' => '100X100',
  'module' => 'frontend',
)
```

please help me :(

Comment: How you create link to controller ?

Comment: **RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)  ../../index/index/app/storage/image/$2/crop/$1 [QSA,L]**

here is the link to controller

Comment: in PHP or HTML how you create link ?

Comment: what do you mean by php or html ???

my problem is when i copy the link of images and past it in address bar , i want to see the resized image , if not resized previously the server must request the IndexController and indexAction , but the server cant  the folder "contents" as a controller and ignored the  index controller in htaccess file !

Comment: If your apache doesn't see .htaccess file. It should be somewhere in the apache config "AllowOverride All". My path for config file is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default (if it's AllowOverride None, correct it)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a module/frontend/Controller/contentsController.php ?
and in this file a userdataAction method ?

Need more information to help you easier.

Comment: no the "contents" just a folder for public files ,  what i need is ! 

when the folder "100x100" or file 163.png not found , i need to request the IndexConroller ,


files structure is  
--index.php
--contents
----images
-----src

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule will never match the requested url : localhost/cmstest/public/contents/userdata/images/100X100/163.png as you expect

With this rule :
    ^(.*)/(.*), 
you are writing that the requested url begin by something with the ^ character following by a slash and others characters.

Here, your URI is public/contents/userdata/images/100X100/163.png. So it will be never matched as you expect.

try something like :

```
RewriteRule ^public/contents/userdata/images/(.*)/(.*)  ../../index/index/app/storage/image/$2/crop/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that something to occur - a particular controller/action is invoked - only when a url is not found, then one way to implement that is to perform a check in your `ErrorController::errorAction()` and forward to the controller/action that performs the required handling.

Specifically:

1. In `ErrorController::errorAction()`, check that the error that got you there is a 404-error.
2. If so, check (perhaps a `preg_match()` on the `$request->getRequestUri()`) that the url requested is of the type your wish to handle with your resize routine(`IndexController::resizeAction()` or the like).
3. If so, then perform a `$this->_forward('resize', 'index')` so that your resize routine can perform the resize, save the resized image (so it will be served next time without the need for the resizer), and send the now-resized image (complete with correct image headers).